# How to grant access to a table built in SAS

Tags: sas, database-administration

Hi I have the following table called "Cohmon" stored in a Library called "JANUS" (shown below).

How do I grant Access to all for the "COHMON" table?

The Library was created as so:

`libname JANUS '/sasdata/mids_output02/rjs/';`

Is it something like:

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA "JANUS" TO USERS;`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the library folder was created on the server and how the libref defining libname statement was submitted.  Essentially the account used to login to the SAS Server will need read/write access to the libref's folder at the operating system level, and read/write access to the libref granted through SAS metadata settings.

The librefs of form `"<SAS Server> - <folder>"` are folders that can be administered through the metadata server and the SAS Management Console, Folders tab.

The other librefs can require operating system level commands to set permissions to read and write to the folder.  For example in Linux

```
chmod 755 /sasdata/mids_output02/rjs/
```

will grant all accounts on the server read access to the folder and thus read access to the data sets within (providing the .sas7bdat files also allow for reading)

If you have set up user groups on the server you can be more judicious in the operating system level

```
chown :sasusers /sasdata/mids_output02/rjs/
chmod 775 /sasdata/mids_output02/rjs/
```

At this point, any EG user account on the machine who is in OS group sasusers will have full access to the folder, and thus in SAS via the libref `JANUS`.